# Strings having at-least one character but not just a specific one

Tags: regex, xsd

I've tried searching around for answers but could not easily find one on SO. Please re-direct if this is a repeat question:

Need to ensure strings are valid with:
`[\p{L}\p{N}+-]+`

Now this ensures the strings will have at-least of one valid unicode letters, a number or the symbols + and -

I have a specific scenario where I do not want the string to contain just + and -

These symbols should be allowed only if the are preceded or succeeded by a valid letter or a number.

Comment: Doesn't that mean you only need to test for `\p{L}` only? Currently, your regex is unanchored, or how are you using it? Where? A possible solution is `^(?!.*[-+]{2})[\p{L}\p{N}+-]+$`

Comment: Make your question more clear showing example of strings that are well formatted or not.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Supposed to be part of XML Schema definition to match pattern of a string. I suppose / guess anchoring means usage of ^ and ending with $ (Sorry, I do not know what that means)

CasimiretHippolyte It seems the question is pretty clear. Acceptable strings are ones with at-least one character which should be a letter from any language, a number or characters + and - The only catch is the string cannot be all + and -

Comment: Ok, that makes it clear. XML Schema patterns are anchored by default. And you cannot use lookarounds. You need `<xs:pattern value="[-+]?[\p{L}\p{N}]+([-+][\p{L}\p{N}]+)*[-+]?"/>` - check https://regex101.com/r/a5SxHW/1

Comment: Can the `-` and `+` be located at the beginning or end of the string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, that's fine, they can be at the beginning or end of string.

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
<xs:pattern value="[-+]?[\p{L}\p{N}]+([-+][\p{L}\p{N}]+)*[-+]?"/>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a5SxHW/1)

Since XML Schema regexps are anchored by default the pattern matches the entire string that meets the following sequence of patterns:

- `[-+]?` - a single optional `-` or `+`
- `[\p{L}\p{N}]+` - 1+ letters/digits
- `([-+][\p{L}\p{N}]+)*` - 0 or more sequences of

  - `[-+]` - a single `-` or `+`
  - `[\p{L}\p{N}]+` - 1+ letters/digits
- `[-+]?` - a single optional `-` or `+`

Comment: Perfect. This is working fine like I expected. And thanks for breaking it up and explaining.